# Using \textsc{} manually in section

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am using textsc in section by manually adjusting fontsize between normal size and script size. For example:

```
\section{P\scriptsize ROGRAMMING \normalsize P\scriptsize ROGRAMMING}
```

should produce:

[image]

The first letter P appears to be larger than the second letter P, obviously since `normalsize` has a fontsize less than fontsize of `section`

My question is how can I make the second letter P match the size of the first letter P. I don't want to add another `normalsize` for the first letter P.

Comment: Why don’t you use actual small caps? And adjust the formatting of the section using `titlesec`.

Comment: `\section{P{\scriptsize ROGRAMMING} P{\scriptsize ROGRAMMING}}`. The effect of `\scriptsize` lasts only until the closing brace.

Comment: You could use `\textsc` You should never have fontsize commands in the section argument, the sizes are set by the document class, and are different in the heading, in the table of contents and in page heads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to render *all* section-level headers in bold small-caps, I strongly recommend you tell LaTeX about this, so that LaTeX will do the tedious work for you. E.g., you could load the [sectsty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package and issue a suitable `\sectionfont` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %to enable bold small-caps letters

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\scshape} % render section-level headers in bold small-caps

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\section{Programming Programming}
\end{document}
```